# C# Application with Jazzy UI

Tags: c, winapi, com, wcf-client

I currently have a C Shell with a native browser (IE) Embedded Can i anyhow use WPF /WCF in this ?
 I am talking total Client Side not a launcher app ?

Wanted something cool and Jazzy with respect to UI

Comment: You wanted something *Jazzy*? Could you please give your definition of this adjective?

Comment: I'm confused exactly what you want? Do you want to develop a WPF application?

Comment: I dont want to create a WPF Application. I want to use WPF in my existing C Application which is embedding a browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dotnet desktop application is always preferred for WPF and WCF. This can be done using C But it will be too much code and without any guarantee if the code will properly function or not.

So best is to create the dotnet application rather than C Application.